# duplicate entry: android/support/v4/graphics/drawable/DrawableCompatHoneycomb.class

Tags: android, android-studio

After changing minimum sdk to 16 i've got that error

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'. > com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: android/support/v4/graphics/drawable/DrawableCompatHoneycomb.class

this is my build.gradle (app)

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "24.0.2"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.nicoleiesperida.crazyjeepney"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    multiDexEnabled true
    ndk {
        moduleName "player_shared"
    }
}
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}
externalNativeBuild {
    ndkBuild {
        path 'src/main/jni/Application.mk'
    }
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
}
productFlavors {
}
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:+'
compile files('libs/dagger-1.2.2.jar')
compile files('libs/javax.inject-1.jar')
compile files('libs/nineoldandroids-2.4.0.jar')
compile files('libs/support-v4-19.0.1.jar')
compile 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.+'
}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you are using local jars instead of retrieving from the maven repo?

Comment: Jar files contained within the `libs/` folder do not play nicely with each other. Also, do not compile all the google play services, and definitely do not use `:+`. Actually use a version. https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup

Comment: And, by the way, [NineOldAndroids is deprecated](https://github.com/JakeWharton/NineOldAndroids)

Answer (score 0):

The same class is being provided by two different dependencies. run

```
gradle app:dependencies
```

or

```
./gradlew app:dependencies
```

where app is the app project name. Then locate the support v4 package and exclude it from the dependency. Probably it's facebook.

Comment: i already exclude the v4 package
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
}